# Adding IE11 to the apps list in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

How can I add IE11 to the apps list in windows 10.  I've added it to the task bar as well as one of the tiles but I can't find a way of adding it to the list of apps. I've also made it my default web browser.  At least I think I have.

Comment: `At least I think I have`? If you give us facts, then fine. but this is of no help.

Answer (score 1):

It is buried in the Windows Accessories folder in the all apps list.

[image]

When you find it in that folder, right click on Internet Explorer link in Windows Accessories and select "pin to start"

[image]

Now it will show up on the right side under "Life at a Glance", just click+drag it to wherever you want on that side. I dragged mine to the top if the tile list.

[image]